# Make Switch component respect URL fragments with React Router?

Tags: react-router

How can I do hash routing with React Router?

This works fine:

```
return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <Link to="/one">One</Link>
          <Link to="/two">Two</Link>
        </div>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/one" component={One} />
          <Route exact path="/two" component={Two} />
          <Route component={Three} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
```

However this always renders component Three:

```
return (
      <div>
        <div>
          <Link to="/#one">One</Link>
          <Link to="/#two">Two</Link>
        </div>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/#one" component={One} />
          <Route exact path="/#two" component={Two} />
          <Route component={Three} />
        </Switch>
      </div>
    );
```

Do I need the hash router for this? I don't find the docs very clear:

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/HashRouter

Answer (score 0):

Component *Three* is rendered because that's the default one whenever there is no routing point that matches a given URL.

You're right, you should use *HashRouter* provided by the *react-router-dom* package. Based on the [documentation](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom/docs/api/HashRouter.md#hashrouter), the appropriate configuration should be something similar to this in your case:

```
import { HashRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

<HashRouter basename="/" hashType="noslash">
   <App />
</HashRouter>
```

Thereby the root path is changed to */#*.

To stick to your example:

```
<div>
   <div>
      // http://localhost:3000/#one
      <Link to="/#one">One</Link> // This can be either /one or /#one
      <Link to="/#two">Two</Link>
   </div>
   <Switch>
      <Route exact path="/one" component={One} />
      <Route exact path="/two" component={Two} />
      <Route component={Three} />
   </Switch>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, the *path* prop should be the same as before.

The documentation also contains an example of how the router creates the href links in this situation.